# ¿Como puedo redireccionar a otra ruta sin recargar la pagina en Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angularjs, typescript

Soy algo nuevo en angular y quiero hacer una página más bonita del lado del cliente, es decir que teniendo un navbar el cliente pueda hacer click a esos vínculos y que estos no me recarguen y me hagan el redireccionamiento de la pagina, lo que quiero lograr es que al momento de realizar el click en la url se cambie la dirección a otra vista, pero que esto no me recargue la página, lo he visto en algunos sitios y me parece muy interesante, si alguien me puedo ayudar lo agradecería demasiado.

Comment: Lo que describes se llama routers https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Puedes dar un enfoque más directo a lo que deseas hacer, no se entiende muy bien, puedes mostrar lo que has echo hasta el momento

Comment: Es un poco confusa la pregunta, angular por defecto crea una estructura que permite navegar entre paginas o componentes sin tener que recargar la pagina como bien dice @jotade simplemente debes seguir la documentación de los routers de angular :D